# Как использовать CircularReveal?

Tags: android, анимация, material-design, android-animation

Хочу поставить CircularReveal, не могу разобраться с этой библиотекой. Не получается сделать ее рабочей, хоть и onClick поставил. Ничего не происходит, даже ошибок не выдает. Вот мой код

```
final View myView = v.findViewById(R.id.awesome_card);

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int dx = Math.max(cx, myView.getWidth() - cx);
    int dy = Math.max(cy, myView.getHeight() - cy);
    float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(dx, dy);

    SupportAnimator animator =
            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(1500);

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    animator.start()
```

XMl - код

```
<io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Put more views here if you want, it's stock frame layout  -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/awesome_card"
        style="@style/CardView"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>
```

добавил в build.gradle следующее:

```
compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

build.gradle (глобальный)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

Вот сама библиотека - https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal

Еще сайт, откуда я брал OnClick - http://stfalcon.com/blog/post/android-material-design

Comment: приведите разметку и build.gradle

Comment: что то странно, и даже никаких ошибок и предупреждений не выводит?

Comment: просто метод `addListener()` требует `AnimatorListener`, а у Вас там `AnimatorListenerAdapter` и ошибки не выдает, может понапутали чего с импортами.

Comment: Вынесите логику в отдельный метод, что-то мне подсказывает  что ваши cx, су, dx, dy  равны нулю

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: http://stfalcon.com/blog/post/android-material-design я еще смотрел здесь. Там и скопировал адаптер

Comment: Ох как страдает разметка в этом `CircularRevel`!

Answer (score 1):

Окей, я вырвал код из своего тестового проекта. Думаю, разберетьсь :D Здесь фаб стоит между двумя контейнерами, изначально с картинкой плюсика. При нажатии на фаб он анимацией поворота превращается в крестик и из его центра идет волна на верхний контейнер. При повторном нажатии волна обратно задвигается в центр в фаб и он обратно превращается а плюсик

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BF0E2F"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="#9220BE"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, Morph!"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_add"
    app:backgroundTint="#8D1B14"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class FABMorph extends AppCompatActivity
{
    boolean morph = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fabmorph);
        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabm);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        final LinearLayout shape = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewA);
        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams vmlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
        shape.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        shape.setEnabled(false);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        setTitle(title);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (morph)
                    {
                        RotateAnimation ranim_close = new RotateAnimation(45f, 0f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        ranim_close.setFillAfter(true);
                        ranim_close.setDuration(250L);
                        fab.startAnimation(ranim_close);
                        Animator animatorz = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(shape, shape.getWidth() / 2, shape.getHeight(), (float) Math.hypot(shape.getWidth(), shape.getHeight()), 0);
                        animatorz.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                        animatorz.setDuration(4000);
                        animatorz.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                                {
                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                    shape.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
                        animatorz.start();
                        morph = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RotateAnimation ranim_close = new RotateAnimation(0f, 45f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        ranim_close.setFillAfter(true);
                        ranim_close.setDuration(250L);
                        fab.startAnimation(ranim_close);
                        Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(shape, shape.getWidth() / 2, shape.getHeight(), 0, (float) Math.hypot(shape.getWidth(), shape.getHeight()));
                        shape.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                        if (shape.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            animator.setDuration(4000);
                            animator.start();
                            morph = true;
                        }}}});}}
```